# How to share one IsolatedStorage for two Windows Forms Applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, isolatedstorage

I have two Windows Forms applications and library in one solution.

Library class can create new folders and files in IsolatedStorage and list all files and folders in IsolatedStorage.

First application uses library class to create new folders/files
I want the second one to list folders created by first app.
How can i make them use the same isolated storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly` to create isolated storage from the library.

Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforassembly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You could use the below type in your library. And the application1 and application2 can write/read to/from the **same isolated storage** via the below type in your library.

Below:

```
 public class UserSettingsManager
    {
        private IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage;
        private readonly String applicationDirectory;
        private readonly String settingsFilePath;

        public UserSettingsManager()
        {
            this.isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForAssembly();
            this.applicationDirectory = "UserSettingsDirectory";
            this.settingsFilePath = String.Format("{0}\\settings.xml", this.applicationDirectory);
        }

        public Boolean WriteSettingsData(String content)
        {
            if (this.isolatedStorage == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (! this.isolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(this.applicationDirectory))
            {
                this.isolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(this.applicationDirectory);
            }

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream =
                this.isolatedStorage.OpenFile(this.settingsFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {

                streamWriter.Write(content);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public String GetSettingsData()
        {
            if (this.isolatedStorage == null)
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }

            using(IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream =
                this.isolatedStorage.OpenFile(this.settingsFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

The dll should be a strongly named assembly. Below snapshots show how to add a strong name to the assembly.
[image: Go to Project properties]

[image: In the Signing tab of the properties, Click on "New" drop down item and provide a snk name in the dialog]

Comment: Hi, I'm doing something wrong. I have created two winforms one to WriteSettingsData second to GetSettingsData and library class with your code. First one works good and creates new folder with xml file, but second one can't read this folder i have error: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException. Do i have to do something with those winforms to use same folder?

Comment: I saw that when i'm running second winform it creates new folder in isolatedstorage (instead of using same folder as first winform)

Comment: The dll in which you have added my code should be strongly named assembly. See the attached snapshot under the edit in my answer.