# Get an IsolatedStorage scope that can be used by several assemblies

Tags: .net, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to use an isolated storage that can be shared by multiple assemblies at the same time. So, I want to use isolated storage scoped to the user *only*, since the assemblies sharing the scope can have separate identities and domains. However, apparently you can't have isolated storage scoped to the user only (GetStore throws an exception saying it's an invalid combination)

How can I get an isolated storage scope that is shared between arbitary assemblies and applications? The code I'm writing can be used on desktop, silverlight or WP7 applications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167622/how-to-share-one-isolatedstorage-for-two-windows-forms-applications

this will help you for sure..

Comment: The code will end up in different assemblies, so this won't help.